# How do I add TypeScript files in a Django project made with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, django, typescript, visual-studio

Is it possible to use *TypeScript* instead of *JavaScript* in a *Django* project developed using *Visual Studio*?

At the moment I just tried to add a *.ts* file and import it to a HTML file. It fails when finding non-Javascript syntax though. I was wondering what I was missing.

Do I have to configuration Visual Studio for it? (TypeScript sdk is already installed).
Is it going to compile the *.ts* files into *JavaScript* by itself or do I have to go through extra steps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to have to compile your Typescript files in Javascript files.

The best way to do this is to use the `tsc` command available to you when installing typescript with a package manager like NPM.

Make sure you then import your *Javascript* files in your HTML files. If you're using [Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/), then use [Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) to link to the appropriate Javascrpt files.

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: I got to the solution by myself, but this is the answer I would have liked to receive back then ;)